# Bypassing Chrome policy settings

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm using Chrome policy settings to restrict access in a user's browser.  Among the policies in place are policies that should prevent deleting history, and also prevent using incognito mode.  On Windows machine, these policies are set like this, if in a .reg file:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome]
"IncognitoModeAvailability"=dword:00000001
"AllowDeletingBrowserHistory"=dword:00000000
```

When tested on a machine that has these policies, it does indeed appear that the users of the machine are unable to use incognito mode, nor delete browser history.  But inspecting the browser history shows large gaps of time without any activity, which is contrast to other logging I have in place.  The user's login does not have have administrative rights (they login as a standard user), so they shouldn't be able to alter the group policy settings.  And indeed when I inspect the machine after the fact, the policies do appear to be active.  My question is, is there any way to bypass these groups policy settings such that either incognito mode may be used, or else browser history is deleted?  Without administrative privileges (so that policies can be changed), I can't imagine how it would be done, but I'm convinced it is.

Comment: Maybe they're using a special utility that modifies the history database file directly.

Comment: Thanks w0xx0m.  Yeah, maybe.  I guess I need add extra logging (maybe keystroke logging) to find out.

Comment: Try logging which applications ran. It could be even a built-in audit in Windows.

Comment: I did install a keystroke logger.  It confirmed sites were browsed not recorded in Chrome history.  It also showed an innocent list of applications used during the day.  The key logger does some screenshots, but not with enough granularity to show exactly what they did.  The keys logged showed nothing interesting leading up to the unrecorded browser use.

Comment: Apps can be launched using mouse as well. And the name may be deceptive...

Comment: Yeah, the keystroke logger will catch apps that are started by mouse too.  The name being recorded is the process name and path.  Do you think those names could be deceptive as well?

Comment: Interesting... I'm pretty sure the same thing is happening on Linux too.  I have the same policies in place there (and they show as set in chrome://policy), but I'm pretty convinced either incognito mode is activated there, or browser history is being deleted.

Comment: I think I finally figured this out.  They were using Chrome's guest mode.  Doing so sorta puts Chrome into incognito mode, where history isn't saved nor are cookies.  This can be blocked with BrowserGuestModeEnabled policy